# PHP password complexity checker code not working

Tags: php, passwords, complexity-theory

I have the following PHP code which is attempting to check for password complexity however when I run it, I don't seem to get valid results (see below)

```
while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {

    $r1='/[A-Z]/';  //Uppercase
    $r2='/[a-z]/';  //lowercase
    $r3='/[!@#$%^&*()-_=+{};:,<.>]/';  // whatever you mean by 'special char'
    $r4='/[0-9]/';  //numbers


if (!preg_match_all($r4, odbc_result($rs,"U_password"))) {
    echo "Password doesn't contain numbers: " . odbc_result($rs,"U_Mailbox") . "@" . odbc_result($rs,"U_Domain") . " " .  odbc_result($rs,"U_password") . "<br>\n";
}

if (!preg_match_all($r2, odbc_result($rs,"U_password"))) {
    echo "Password doesn't contain lowercase letters: " . odbc_result($rs,"U_Mailbox") . "@" . odbc_result($rs,"U_Domain") . " " .  odbc_result($rs,"U_password") . "<br>\n";
}

if (!preg_match_all($r1, odbc_result($rs,"U_password"))) {
    echo "Password doesn't contain  uppercase letters: " . odbc_result($rs,"U_Mailbox") . "@" . odbc_result($rs,"U_Domain") . " " .  odbc_result($rs,"U_password") . "<br>\n";
}
```

}

Output:

Password doesn't contain lowercase letters: jason@domain.com lowercasepw
Password doesn't contain enough numbers: service@domain.com 8B_dip+3
Password doesn't contain  uppercase letters: barry@domain.com Barrywidg@t1o

(By the way the passwords above are NOT real. I have simply swapped lowercase letters for other lower case letters, and upper case letters for other uppercase letters, and numbers for other numbers.)

So I'm perplexed as to why my code is not working. Can anyone else help?

Thanks
Brad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Change `preg_match_all` to `preg_match`.
2. In your special character regular expression, you have several regex chars that are not escaped.  Here it is esacaped: `/[\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=+\{\};:,<\.>]/`

No guarantee that that's 100% of the problem though...

Comment: Thanks - that appeared to be it.

Answer (score 2):

after converting your example to standalone code (please post that in the future)

I get a bunch of these:

`PHP Warning:  preg_match_all() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given in /Users/cabbey/foo.php on line 9`

You should probably turn up error reporting.

I assume since you used _all, that you wanted to count them, in which case you'll want to change your regexps to not be greedy too.

```
$r1='/[A-Z]{1}/';  //Uppercase
$r2='/[a-z]{1}/';  //lowercase
$r3='/[!@#$%^&*()_=+{};:,<.>-]{1}/';  // whatever you mean by 'special char'
$r4='/[0-9]{1}/';  //numbers

$found = array();

foreach (array('lowercasepw', '8B_dip+3', 'Barrywidg@t1o') as $pass) {

    if (!preg_match_all($r4, $pass, $found)) {
        echo "Password doesn't contain numbers: $pass\n";
    } else {
        echo "found ".count($found[0])." numbers\n";
    }

    if (!preg_match_all($r2,$pass, $found)) {
        echo "Password doesn't contain lowercase letters: $pass\n";
    } else {
        echo "found ".count($found[0])." lowercase\n";
    }

    if (!preg_match_all($r1, $pass, $found)) {
        echo "Password doesn't contain  uppercase letters: $pass\n";
    } else {
        echo "found ".count($found[0])." uppercase\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match_all` accepts three parameters, not two: the third one being a reference to an array that will be populated with matches. Use `preg_match`.

Also, make sure those special characters are escaped if they are part of the PCRE syntax (e.g.: `\.` instead of `.`).

I suggest you increase `error_reporting` and/or activate `display_errors` and/or error logging. If you had, this is something that would have been caught as it spits a E_WARNING error.

Comment: Thanks, I was checking phperror.log but maybe I don't have logging cranked up high enough.